# how to group together functions with different number of parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters

I would like to group together different search algorithms in a single loop. However, I don't know how to include algorithms with different number of parameters. Loop is this:

```
search_algorithms = [linearSearch, jumpSearch, exponentialSearch]

        for i in range(len(search_algorithms)):
            start = default_timer()
            result = search_algorithms[i](arr, len(arr), target)
            end = default_timer()
            time = timedelta(seconds=end-start)

            print("{}".format(search_algorithms[i].__name__))
            print("Target element is present at index", result)
            print("Searching executed in {} seconds \n".format(time))
```

Is there some simple way how to include for instance binary search defined as `def binarySearch(arr, l, r, x):`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: where do the arguments come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the list of tuples in `search_algorithms` where the first element is a function, and the second one is a list of arguments.

```py
search_algorithms = [
    (linearSearch, [arg1, arg2]),
    (jumpSearch, [arg1]),
    (exponentialSearch, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
]

for fn, args in search_algorithms:
    fn(*args)
```